# Problem in converting Procedural to OO in tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I wrote a script using tkinter in Procedural manner, which worked correctly:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

Experiment = tk.StringVar()

list1 = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Custom...']

def new_label(Experiment):
    if (Experiment == 'Custom...'):
        label_6 = tk.Label(master,
              text='Experiment',
              relief = 'solid',
              width=20,
              font=('arial',10,'bold')).pack()
Experiment.set('Experiment')
droplist = tk.OptionMenu(master, Experiment, *list1, command = new_label)

droplist.config(width=20)
droplist.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

However, when I tried to use Object Oriented approach:

```
import tkinter as tk


class demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.Experiment = tk.StringVar()

        self.Experiment.set('Experiment')
        list1 = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Custom...']
        self.droplist = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.Experiment, *list1, command = self.new_label)

        self.droplist.config(width=20)
        self.droplist.pack()

    def new_label(self):
        if (self.Experiment == 'Custom...'):
            label_6 = tk.Label(self.master,
                  text='Experiment',
                  relief = 'solid',
                  width=20,
                  font=('arial',10,'bold')).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
app = demo1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I faced this error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/majido/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line
>   1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "/home/majido/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 3442,
>   in **call**
>       self.__callback(self.__value, *args) TypeError: new_label() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

which I could not relate to what I have already coded, I did not pass anything.

Answer (score 0):

`OptionMenu`'s `command` callback receives the option that the user selected, which your method doesn't take (it only takes an implicit `self`). Note how in your first version, the function takes an `Experiment`, but doesn't in your second version. You need to at least add a dummy parameter so the `new_label` callback takes the correct number of arguments:

```
def new_label(self, _):  # An "unnamed" parameter to handle the unneeded data given to the callback
    . . .
```

Or, just create a wrapper function that throws out the passed argument for you:

```
self.droplist = tk.OptionMenu(. . ., command = lambda _: self.new_label())
```